# JS keycodes not the same as websites say?

Tags: javascript

When I look onto any website that shows JS keycodes, I see that the f# buttons are 112-123, and that 's' is 83. However, I made my website console.log() the keycode of the key I press, and 's' came up as 115. The f# keys don't show up at all. Can someone please help?

Code is just

```
body.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
   var x = event.keyCode;
   console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: [MDN says `keyCode` is deprecated and shouldn't be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):  "You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time."

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider upper and lower case.
    `S` is 83.  `s` is 115.